# Multiple Active Themes

Tags: theming

is it possible to have more than one active theme? Basically what I'm trying to achieve is another theme that has none of the extra CSS/JS output by Drupal modules -- this would only be used for E-Newsletter display. I see the "default" setting for a theme, but how would I apply certain content types, etc to a specific theme? I've searched a bit and am stuck in the mud at the moment. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Themekey module](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) has that functionality built in:

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, **node-type**, and many, many other properties

Answer (score 1):

1. For this requirement you can use the only one tpl to the active
   theme folder page-your_content_type_name.tpl.php.Here you can copy
   the page.tpl.php and paste.then remove the unwanted variable print
   over that page.(Remove print $styles for remove all css adding by
   your module).
2. To alter the rendering of that particular content type use node-content_type_name.tpl.php in themes folder

Answer (score 1):

[Page theme](http://drupal.org/project/page_theme) module works very well for me.

Simply add the desired themes and specify theme's pages.

Let's say your content type is name "cars" and your node urls all start with `http://www.yousite.com/cars/something`, simply add `cars/*` to your theme's page list.